# C# MVC disable binding Controller Method Name to Action property of the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

The problem is - my controller binds method name to the "Action" property of my model and of course it causes error in my model state because *Method Name is String* and my *Action property is Object*. I want the Action property to be null when it is not present in my Formdata.

**Form data:**

[image]

**Model state on processing POST request:**

[image]

**My controller action:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RouteRoleActionsSave(TskRouteRoleAction model,List<TskAction.Actions> RoleActions = null)
    {
        using (var context = new SmartDbContext())
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               return Json("ok");
            }
            return Json(ModelState);
        }
    }
```

**My Model:**

```
[Table("TSK_ROUTE_ROLE_ACTIONS")]
public class TskRouteRoleAction
{
    [Key, Column("ROUTE_ID", Order = 0), ForeignKey("Route")]
    public decimal RouteId { get; set; }
    public TskRoute Route { get; set; }

    [Key, Column("ROLE_ID", TypeName = "numeric", Order = 1), ForeignKey("Role")]
    public TskRole.Roles? RoleId { get; set; }
    public TskRole Role { get; set; }

    [Key, Column("ACTION_ID", TypeName = "numeric", Order = 2), ForeignKey("Action")]
    public TskAction.Actions? ActionId { get; set; }
    public TskAction Action { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Unless you need to bind some value to that property, you can try excluding property [Bind(Exclude="MemberType")]  , or specify custom name using BindProperty  attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploring the documentation i've noticed that the problem is caused by my route mapping that is using the "Action" parameter name in it, so it was conflicting with Action property of my model:

[image]

I've fixed it by adding a binding prefix to my Form, so no conflicting binding paramers longer exists:

[image]